# Binding from parents Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a view that has a `listbox` in it. I have the `listbox` bound to a collection of  ListBoxViewModel which is a property of MainViewModel.  I then have a `dataTemplate` for the `listbox` in which im binding to the properties of the ListBoxViewModel. The view that contains the listbox has datacontext set to the mainVeiwModel.  How can I bind to properties of the MainViewModel in the `dataTemplate` of the `listbox` that has its `ItemSource` bound to the collection of ListBoxVIewModels?

This `combobox` is in the `listBox` `datatemplate` which has its `itemsoucrce` bound to the collection of ListBoxViewModels.  Notice im trying to bind to MainViewModel properties as well as ListBoxViewModel properties with in the `datatemplate`

```
      <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Path=CollectionOfListBoxViewModelsInMainViewModel}"
           <DataTemplate>
               .....
                <ComboBox Margin="6"
                          Width="300"
                          IsEditable="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainViewModelProperty}" //binding not working
                          SelectedItem="{Binding ListBoxViewModelProperty}"  //binding works
                          Text="{Binding ListBoxViewModelProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>   //binding works
                .....
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
<YOURWINDOW x:Name="MyWindow">
 <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Path=CollectionOfListBoxViewModelsInMainViewModel}"
           <DataTemplate>
               .....
                <ComboBox Margin="6"
                          Width="300"
                          IsEditable="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=DataContext.MainViewModelProperty}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding ListBoxViewModelProperty}"  //binding works
                          Text="{Binding ListBoxViewModelProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>   //binding works
                .....
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox>
</YOURWINDOW>
```

1) Remember that MyWindow must have set DataContext to MainViewModel. You can use any UI element, it doesn't have to be Window. 
2) Second solution is to use RelativeSource instead of ElementName.

Comment: Great, I think that did it, I just had to give the control a name.  Thanks!